# Updating Activity on receiving through Service

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I have an application which uses an `IntentService` to handle incoming Google Cloud Messaging messages. Currently I am creating a notification whenever I get a message through the `onHandleIntent()` function. The notification opens up a specific activity and then does some calculations and updates the UI. I'm trying to make my implementation such that if I am already on the Activity that the notification will open, then the Service should be able to update the UI without having to send a notification. I am assuming I can use a broadcast receiver to do this, but I am not sure how to implement it such that it should update the Activity only if that Activity is running else it should post a notification.

I am not sure how to do the following:

1. Check if the specific Activity is already running.
2. If the Activity is already running then perform the required Calculations and UI updates without having to call `startActivity()`

**EDIT:** I have made some changes to my code but I am not see the logcat messages that I have added in the onReceive() method.

I've added the following code to the onHandle() function in my IntentService class:

```
Intent in = new Intent("com.example.gcm.DataActivity");
sendBroadcast(in);
```

"com.example.gcm" is my package name and DataActivity is the name of the Activity.

I've added the following code to my Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(TAG, "start");
      receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d(TAG, "notif received");
        }

    };

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As promised the easy way:
you basically send the broadcast synchroniously and if there is a receiver, you'll set a static flag in your service class, which let's the service know it's already handled:

```
public class TestService extends IntentService {
    public volatile static boolean isHandled = false;
    public static final String INTENT_ACTION_HANDLEGCM = "com.intentexample.gcm";

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        ...
        Intent toActivityIntent = new Intent();
        toActivityIntent.setAction(INTENT_ACTION_HANDLEGCM);
        // toActivity: put other stuff into extras, which you need to update your UI
        TestService.isHandled = false;
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcastSync(toActivityIntent);
        if (!TestService.isHandled) {
            // post your notification to the notification bar
        }
    }
}
```

and register & unregister the broadcast receiver with the intent filter for INTENT_ACTION_HANDLEGCM in your activities onResume and onPause (remember to use LocalBroadcastManager)

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            TestService.isHandled = true;
            // update the UI
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(TestService.INTENT_ACTION_HANDLEGCM));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }
}
```

NOTE: this code is untested, but should give you the general idea. I personally wouldn't do it this way except:

- under time pressure
- the feature is a minor feature and won't be extended anytime soon.

Comment: Is INTENT_ACTION_HANDLEGCM supposed to be the package name? Or is it supposed to be the Activity name?

Comment: any unique String would do it, usually you'd add your package name in front of it, so that it doesn't collide with other intent actions.

Comment: If it is any unique String, then what is the point of using it? How is the Activity able to tell that it should receive that particular broadcast?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your answer. How am I supposed to register the broadcast receiver? The above example shows how to create a new one, but does that also register it?

Comment: I've edited the answer, have a look at new IntentFilter(TestService.INTENT_ACTION_HANDLEGCM), when creating my intent filter in the activty, i use the static from my TestService (that's why it's public)

Comment: I'm getting an error when I try to modify the UI. It says only the original thread that modified a view can touch that view. Is the onReceive() method not running on the UI thread?

Comment: oh, i thought it would run on the ui thread. Seems like you need to post it to the UI thread then. use runOnUiThread(Runnable)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed this in an app by using a SharedPreferences value as to whether the activity is visible or not:

```
    @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("RVisibleNow",true);
    editor.commit();
}
```

and

```
    @Override
protected void onStop() {

    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("RVisibleNow",false);
    editor.commit();

    super.onStop();
}
```

then, yes, using a BroadcastReceiver such as:

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String theRow = intent.getStringExtra(GCMIntentService.MESSAGE);
        String theQuery="SELECT * FROM listdata WHERE _id ='" + theRow + "'"; 
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(action.equals("com.you.yourapp.UpdateList")){
...
```

Oh, and in your GCM service:

```
public static final String BROADCAST = "com.you.yourapp.UpdateList";
public static final String MESSAGE = "com.you.yourapp.GCMIntentService.MESSAGE";

... 

    if(RVisibleNow){
                sendBroadcast(context, message, insertOrUpdate);
            }else{
                generateNotification(context, message, insertOrUpdate);
            }
```

In my case, with a lot of omitted code, my sendBroadcast looked like:

```
private void sendBroadcast(Context context,  String message, String whichFunction){
    String putExtraParam = "something";
    Intent in = new Intent(BROADCAST);
    in.putExtra(MESSAGE, putExtraParam);
    context.sendBroadcast(in);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm confused about the sendBroadcast() method. I see that it only takes 2 arguments (Intent, String), but you have given 3. Can you clarify this? What is the intent supposed to be and what is the String?

Comment: if you decide to go the broadcast way, have a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html

Comment: The sendBroadcast method is just my own way of passing variable values. My response has more to do with a) setting a preferences value as to whether or not your activity is visible; and then b) either generating a notification or updating your UI based on that.

Comment: I made some changes to my code, but the onReceive method is not getting called when I get a message from GCM. I've added the code to my question

Comment: In onCreate: registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(GCMIntentService.BROADCAST));

Comment: In onResume: LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver((receiver), new IntentFilter(GCMIntentService.BROADCAST)); and, as a class function: private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {   is what worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using an IntentService couple with a BroadcastReceiver. 
With that approach your service could notify your activity, but your service wouldn't be able to decide if the broadcast has been received or not (that's the idea of a broadcast, the sender just broadcasts and and doesn't care if there is a receiver or not).

A better approach, though more complicated is:
- use a Service that can be started and bound (Overriding onStartCommand and onBind)
- establish a two-way communication between the service and activity if bound.
- when processing your GCM message, check if there is a communication established, if so: your activity is present, update it (using the communication), if not: go ahead and post your notification.
This is the way i'd recommend, however i understand this seems complex (and is quite some code) therefore i'll give you a second, easier although not really clean code.

Comment: I'm curious about this issue, because of the way I worked around it. Regarding `when processing your GCM message, check if there is a communication established` how is that done?

Comment: When the activity binds (assuming the service runs in the same process) you can simply return the service instance in your Binder (Activity to Service communication - check out the LocalService example in the link below).


Now you can add/remove your own defined listeners as you wish, just by adding public methods to your service eg. : addMyServiceListener(), removeMyServiceListener(). and add/remove them from a Set/Map/List. If the Set/Map/List is empty, you know there is no activity listening.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: however, if you fail to unregister your listener, your might leak your whole activity.